# Using my custom ajax call for load on demand on igHierarchical Grid

Tags: jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am trying to implement the `igHierarchicalGrid` for my application, which can have multiple levels depending on user requirement. I need to use `Load on Demand` feature without oData, so that I can use server's JSON response, parse it and show the results in child grid.

Issues, I am facing is  `How to use my custom ajax call` from which i can send some data to server not necessary the primary key and gets the result in desired format so that the child grid corresponding to that grid is loaded.

I could not find an example for Load on Demand without OData in Jquery.

I tried to give following settings:

// The topmost level

```
var hierarchicalGridConfigs={
        width: "100%",
        initialDataBindDepth: 0,
        dataSourceType: "json",
        dataSource: jsonData,
        oData:false,
        rest:false,
        autoGenerateLayouts: false,
        primaryKey:"id",
        columns:getDefaultColumns(),
        autoGenerateLayouts: false,
        columnLayouts: getColumnLayouts(0,configs,levels-1)
    };
```

For child levels:

```
function getColumnLayouts(i,configs,levels){
    var layouts=[];
    var layout1={};
    /*layout1["name"]="childReports";*/
    /*layout1["dataSourceType"]= "json";*/
    layout1["dataSource"]="myURL";
    layout1["type"]="remoteUrl";
    layout1["autoGenerateColumns"]= false;
    layout1["odata"]= false;
    layout1["rest"]= false;
    layout1["primaryKey"]="id";
    layout1["columns"]=configs[i];
    if(i<levels){
        layout1["columnLayouts"]=getColumnLayouts(++i,configs,levels);
    }  
    layouts.push(layout1);
    return layouts;
}
```

But, for child columns, its taking the URL, directly as String which it assumed to be JSON.

How can i make my custom Ajax Call, and how can I pass parameters from parent row in that request.